# What happens with Grub Rescue?

Tags: grub2, wubi, grubrescue

My problem is that I just installed Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi, and since I have Windows XP I decided not to partition my hard drive. The installation went through fine, and when it finished I restarted my computer.

When my computer rebooted, the grub boot screen appeared, with both Ubuntu and Windows XP as choices, and I chose Ubuntu.  However, a couple of commands appeared on the screen including the famous GRUB RESCUE, and I don't know what the command is or what to write in this space.

Please, I'm a newbie, and Ubuntu is my first Linux distribution. What do I do?

---

**Original Text**

mi problema es que acabé de instalar Ubuntu 12.10 por medio de Wubi, ya que tengo Windows XP y no decidí particionar el disco duro.
Se descargó bien, luego reinicié el PC y me apareció para escoger entre los dos sistemas operativos, escogí Ubuntu pero al escogerlo me aparecían un par de comandos y entre ellos el famoso GRUB RESCUE y no sé que comando es, ni sé que escribir en ese espacio. Por favor, soy novato, este Ubuntu sería mi primera distribución Linux, ¿QUÉ HAGO?

Comment: When posting on this site, please use English, which is the default language for the site.

Comment: I recommend not using Wubi, just install it via the livecd. Te recomiendo NO instalar Ubuntu por Wubi por varias razones. Hazlo mejor por el livecd o livedvd, liveusb cualquier cosa live, menos por el Wubi. En realidad la mayoria de estos problemas es por culpa de Windows y como "afecta" el funcionamiento de Wubi.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a `grub rescue` prompt. It's a `grub prompt`. There is a difference - you have many more commands at your disposal - but it's not going to help you much, because it's a fresh install.

Usually when Wubi users experience this it's due to filesystem corruption and you can just run `chkdsk` from Windows or `fsck` from a live CD, but in this case, it's probably a different issue preventing Grub from loading the menu (`grub.cfg`) from the virtual disk (`root.disk`).

Not really sure what could cause this, but it happened to someone else recently - have a look here: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2112111

You can try a few of the commands and see if your problem is the same, and if so, file a bug.